# java util logging message file not generating in users directory

Tags: java, logging

I have configured `util.logging` in my project. Having logging formatter and pattern details in `logging.properties` file and trying to read properties file from java code. But the log is not writting into the file location while declared in the `logging.properties`file.
Please find my code below.

Problem is : `myApp.log` file is not generating in my `users.home` directory. But log message is printing in my eclipse console.

AEvent.java

```
package com.jnlp;
import java.awt.*;  
import java.awt.event.*;  
import java.util.logging.Logger;
class AEvent extends Frame implements ActionListener{  

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private LoadLogPropertiesFile logProp=LoadLogPropertiesFile.getInstance();
     private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoadLogPropertiesFile.class.getName());
TextField tf;  
AEvent(){  
  
    //create components  
    tf=new TextField();  
    tf.setBounds(60,50,170,20);  
    Button b=new Button("click me");  
    b.setBounds(100,120,80,30);  
      
    //register listener  
    b.addActionListener(this);//passing current instance  
      
    //add components and set size, layout and visibility  
    add(b);add(tf);  
    setSize(300,300);  
    setLayout(null);  
    setVisible(true);  
    }  
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){  
    
}  
public static void main(String args[]){  
    logger.info("Test logging....");
    new AEvent();  
}  
}
```

LoadLogPropertiesFile

```
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.util.logging.LogManager;

 public class LoadLogPropertiesFile {

private static LoadLogPropertiesFile instance = new LoadLogPropertiesFile();
public static LoadLogPropertiesFile getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

  static {
      System.out.println("Loading log properties file -->");
      
       String path = LoadLogPropertiesFile.class.getClassLoader().getResource("logging.properties").getFile();
}
```

}

logging.properties

```
# Logging
handlers = java.util.logging.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
.level=INFO

# File Logging
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern=%h/myApp.log
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.FileHandler.level=INFO

# Console Logging
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=INFO
```

Please find my project structure.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you are applying the configuration to the LogManager.  You want to do something like this:

```
 static {
   System.out.println("Loading log properties file -->");
  
   try (InputStream in = LoadLogPropertiesFile.class.getResourceAsStream("logging.properties")) {
       if (in != null) {
           LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(in);
       } else {
          System.err.println("Configuration file not found.");
       }
   }
}
```